# Merge two configuration files during build time in angular 8

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular8

I’m working on an Angular 8.
We have a config file that contains the configuration and we have the app-specific config file. i.e. app.setting.json.
Each project will have its app.config.json file.

config.json look like

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "xyz": false
  },
  "url": {}
}
```

app.setting.json

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "xyz": true
  }
}
```

We have implemented a service i.e. readConfigService that reads config.json file and returns its content to the app.
currently what I'm doing here is, in readConfigService, reading both the .json files using HTTP request and merging it in a single object and returning the same to the app.

Instead of merging it at runtime, finding a better approach to do the same during build time. i.e. ( ng build app name).
so after building the project, config.json should look like

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "xyz": true
  },
  "url": {}
}
```

is there any way to merge the two .json files during build time?